# Transactions on remote EJB calls

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1, corba

I have a weird problem concerning transactions and CORBA in glassfish. I could solve the problem but still I have no idea why this error happens:

I got two classes, lets call them **Client** and **RemoteImpl**. **Client** is on one server, **Remote** on another server.

**Client** looks like this (simpler example, not the real code):

```
@Stateless
public class Client {

    @EJB(name = "TheRemoteEJB")
    protected Remote remoteEJB;

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*/5", persistent = false)
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void doSomeStuff() {
      for(int i=0;i<300000;i++){
        remoteEJB.theMethodToCall(i);
        ... other code that may take a bit longer...
      }
    }
}
```

**RemoteImpl** looks like this:

```
@Stateless
@Remote(RemoteInterface.class)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class RemoteImpl {

  @EJB
  private SomeJPAFacade facade;

  @Override
  public int theMethodToCall(int param) throws SomeException {
    Bean products = facade.findBySomeSelect(param);
    return bean.getAValue();
  }
}
```

Other used classes are:

**SomeException**:

```
public class SomeException extends Exception {
 public SomeException() {
   super();
 }
 public SomeException(String message) {
   super(message);
 }
}
```

and **RemoteInterface**

```
public interface RemoteInterface {
  public int theMethodToCall() throws SomeException
}
```

The problem is, when **doSomeStuff** takes too long, a CORBA exception is raised:

```
[#|2012-12-22T03:10:03.327+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|com.foo.bar.Client|_ThreadID=47;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.transaction.InvalidTransactionException: CORBA INVALID_TRANSACTION 0 No
; nested exception is:
    org.omg.CORBA.INVALID_TRANSACTION:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at com.foo.bar.Client._Remote_Wrapper.theMethodToCall(com/foo/bar/_RemoteInterface_Wrapper.java)
    at com.foo.bar.Client.doSomeStuff(Client.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3162.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor80.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundTimeout(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:149)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor371.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.callEJBTimeout(BaseContainer.java:4058)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.deliverTimeout(EJBTimerService.java:1832)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService.access$100(EJBTimerService.java:108)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBTimerService$TaskExpiredWork.run(EJBTimerService.java:2646)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.transaction.InvalidTransactionException: CORBA INVALID_TRANSACTION 0 No; nested exception is:
    org.omg.CORBA.INVALID_TRANSACTION:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:281)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:227)
    at com.foo.bar.__RemoteInterface_Remote_DynamicStub.matchByParityId(com/foo/bar/__RemoteInterface_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.INVALID_TRANSACTION:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
    at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.CurrentTransaction.sendingRequest(CurrentTransaction.java:812)
    at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.SenderReceiver.sending_request(SenderReceiver.java:138)
    at com.sun.jts.pi.InterceptorImpl.send_request(InterceptorImpl.java:338)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.InterceptorInvoker.invokeClientInterceptorStartingPoint(InterceptorInvoker.java:290)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.PIHandlerImpl.invokeClientPIStartingPoint(PIHandlerImpl.java:376)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.beginRequest(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:304)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.request(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:228)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:194)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.omg.CosTransactions.Unavailable: IDL:omg.org/CosTransactions/Unavailable:1.0
    at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.TopCoordinator.get_txcontext(TopCoordinator.java:2787)
    at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.ControlImpl.getTXContext(ControlImpl.java:824)
    at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.CurrentTransaction.sendingRequest(CurrentTransaction.java:804)
    ... 49 more
|#]
```

I explicit told the ApllicationServer `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)` because I do not want to span a transaction. But the exception looks like there was a transaction. I always thought transactions cannot be spanned over a remote call to another glassfish instance?

I could solve the problem by removing the `@TransactionAttribute` and instead adding a `@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)` in **Client**-class.

But still I would like to know why this error happens.

Thanks for your replies.

**UPDATE:**
Bugreport has been filed under: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17535

Answer (score 1):

[NOT_SUPPORTED](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html#NOT_SUPPORTED) means `The container invokes an enterprise bean method whose transaction attribute NOT_SUPPORTED with an unspecified transaction context.`

It seems that that unspecified context is causing the invalid transaction exception.

By using bean managed transaction you are telling the container not to provide any transaction context so it prevents that exception.

This feels like a bug to me, i'm not very familiar with glassfish by my gut feeling tells me this should have worked.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think too, that this is a bug. Perhaps I'm going to file a bugreport.